# How to use multinomial logistic regression for multilabel classification problem?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification

I have to predict the type of program a student is in based on other attributes.

**`prog`** is a categorical variable indicating what type of program a student is in: “General” (1), “Academic” (2), or “Vocational” (3)

**`Ses`** is a categorical variable indicating someone’s socioeconomic class: “Low” (1), “Middle” (2), and “High” (3)

`read`, `write`, `math`, `science` is their scores on different tests

`honors`    Whether they have enrolled or not

[csv file in image format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPTFN.jpg);

```py
import pandas as pd;
import numpy as np;
df1=pd.get_dummies(df,drop_first=True);
X=df1.drop(columns=['prog_general','prog_vocation'],axis=1);
y=df1.loc[:,['prog_general','prog_vocation']];
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split;
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42);
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression;
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report;
clf=LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial',solver='newton-cg');
model=clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

But here I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: bad input shape (140, 2).

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ValueError: bad input shape (140, 2).

Answer (score 3):

As such, `LogisticRegression` does not handle multiple targets. But this is not the case with all the model in Sklearn. For example, all tree based models ([`DecisionTreeClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit)) can handle multi-output natively.

To make this work for `LogisticRegression`, you need a [`MultiOutputClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier) wrapper.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=3, random_state=0)
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(estimator= LogisticRegression()).fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X[-2:])
```