# sklearn LogisticRegression bad input shape error fix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is the x_train

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Here is the y_train:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

used logistic regression:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr=LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Got Error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    758                         dtype=None)
    759     else:
--> 760         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    761         _assert_all_finite(y)
    762     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    795         return np.ravel(y)
    796 
--> 797     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    798 
    799 

ValueError: bad input shape (3, 6)
```

How can we fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like your task is multilabel classification.  Use multi output wrapper.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977692/how-to-use-multinomial-logistic-regression-for-multi-target-classification-probl/62016026#62016026) answer

Comment: Perfect dear , Thank you .Yes, the task was  multilabel classification